# Workflow process with two different mobile app from the same git repo

Tags: android, git, mobile, io, workflow

We have two different mobile apps (pretty similar with a few changes, but this is two different apps on the app store). Theses two apps are build from one git repo (xdode allow us to share the code with different schemes and we have the equivalent for android)

I'm designing a git workflow process to the team and i was planning to use gitflow with a few modifications to fit our needs. But i'm stuck with this two applications in the same git repos and i'm not sure if we should keep it like this and having two app with two differents version on the same git repo, or if separate them in two repos could be a better choice, knowing that  most of the time, the new feature will have to be integrated in the two applications.

My principal concerns about this is that the workflow could become too complex and the git history really messy, not easy to read.

Do you think separate this applications could be a good choice ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use git submodule to help.Make the common part a submodule and then you'll have 3 repos.
When you want to share code from one app to another, just move the code to the submodule.
[Git Submodule Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)